# tecknet webcam drivers

Tags: drivers, webcam

I bought a [tecknet webcam](https://www.amazon.it/dp/B078RYXW7T) but it seems that it doesn't support linux.

I wonder if somebody has experience with this webcam and managed to use it on latest kubuntu.

#### update:

```
OS: Kubuntu 21.10 x86_64
Kernel: 5.13.0-23-generic
```

```
lsusb
...
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1d6c:0103 webcam webcam
...
```

```
cheese
(cheese:20911): cheese-WARNING **: 16:46:09.582: Device '/dev/video2' failed during initialization: ../sys/v4l2/gstv4l2object.c(3983): gst_v4l2_object_set_format_full (): /GstCameraBin:camerabin/GstWrapperCameraBinSrc:camera_source/GstBin:bin18/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src1:
Call to TRY_FMT failed for YUYV @ 800x600: Input/output error
```

it is recognized but still ...
Once the webcam is connected to the desktop, the boot becomes very slow, that's why I think it's a drivers issue.

Comment: The Linux (Android) support is explicitly stated. Considering this is a "plug'n'play" devices across the board it's really doubtful it doesn't work in desktop Linux.

Comment: `it doesn't support linux` -- Did you try it? Please edit to post the output of `lsusb` before and after connecting the webcam. Also, which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi done, what else I can check?

Comment: Install cheese (`sudo apt install cheese`). Does the webcam show up in Cheese?

Answer (score 1):

This device lsusb "Bus 001 Device 015: ID 1d6c:0103" definitely does work in LinuxMint 19.3 which is based on Ubuntu 18.04 (I think) using Cheese, VLC or Zoom with 2K resolution. My make Ansinna Model FH2k cost about £10 from Amazon. Desktop is Xfce4.
(According to this website https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:1d6c-0103 this webcam is used in quite a few PCs.)

However, it is rather tempramental. So here is how I got it working:

1. Uninstall guvcview completely. This is really important because it using it seems to mess with the drivers and make Linux completely unstable. I suspect that the problem lies with the Ansinna Model FH2k 1d6c:0103 that I have and not with guvcview.
2. Plug in usb webcam and in terminal: "lsusb".  You should see the line with  Device ID 1d6c:0103 on mine it is  followed with a blank or "webcam" as the manufacturer.
3. In terminal "ls /dev/video*" should list video0 & video1 for internal webcams on a laptop and video2 & video3 for the 1d6c:0103, or as 0 & 1 if there is no internal webcam.
4. In terminal: 2cheese -d /dev/video0" (or /dev/video2)should use either the internal webcam or the 1d6c:0103.  I used Cheese version 3.28.0. The -d tells Cheese which device to use.

Now for the problem.  If you close cheese then the 1d6c:0103 webcam does not seem to disconnect and it is necessary to unplug it. If you then check "ls /dev/video*" you should see it has gone.
Now plug in webcam again and start from the top with "ls /dev/video*" to check that it is back. If this does not work I usually reboot and start again.

If you try to use Zoom after using Cheese, first unplug the webcam and wait a few seconds before plugging it in again and it should work with Zoom at 2K. In Zoom the green light on the left of my Ansinna FH2K lights up. The red light on the right is constantly lit when it is plugged in.

If you run Zoom after closing Cheese and not unplugging the webcam Zoom seems   to freeze with no error warnings and has to be forcibly stopped.

Sometimes unplugging and reinserting does not work and we have to resort to a reboot. However, remove the usb 1d6c:0103 first or the reboot takes a very long time or may fail altogether. I have no idea why but this has been commented on by others. I imagine one of the system logs will have messages about the problem but so far I have not looked into this.

Running cheese from the terminal shows various error messages which I do not understand at the moment but will probably indicate the source of the problems for those who know.

I have been completely unable to get microphone on the Ansinna to work or show up on "ls /dev/audio*" but I do not intend to use it. It does show up in Pulse Audio Input as "webcam Analogue Mono" but only indicates any sound input if the volume is set above "Base 100% (0db)" which is indicated about half way up the volume scale. According to Amazon the mic should be stereo but so far it seems to be mono.

If the video works but the image is green then try using a different video format. This works in guvcview but that software appears incompatable with this webcam and the whole linux installation becomes unstable and a reboot is required. I found the best course of action to uninstall guvcview completely.

All the above information also applies to LinuxMint20.3 but I have carried out a limited trial of that version.  VLC also works using Device /dev/videoX as found above.  Most of the guidance about how to do this can be found in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam in more detail. I could not find the device 1d6c:0103 listed in any of the Linux help pages other than this one here.

Added later:
Experimenting more, I find that the webcam is far more stable when tested with VLC v3.0.8 than it is with Cheese. To use: plug in webcam, check in terminal "ls /dev/video*" then in VLC click Media (At top Left) > Open Capture Device and select from drop down list in "Video device name" which will be like "/dev/video2". Then click "Play" at the bottom. Audio devices can be selected hw:0,0, hw:1,0 or hw:2,0 but I am not sure what those mean.  Allow plenty of time for the webcam to react to each change: for some reason it takes a few minutes to register changes sometimes.

I hope this helps because this cheap 2K camera seems to work well when it is set up as above.

Kind wishes, Ian.

Comment: Hey Ian, at the moment I cannot check the webcam following your guide but I will try and you know. Thanks for the effort btw

Comment: I look forward to hearing how you get on. Persivere - the webcam seems to take a few minutes to "settle down" after it is plugged in or any changes are made.